# Order by field in many to many relation (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model School which has a belongsToMany relation:

```
class School extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        "url",
        "title",
        "is_own",
    ];

    public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class, "event_school");
    }
}
```

How I can order school by event start_at field? For example, can I do like this?

```
School::whereHas("events")
    ->with([
        "events" => function ($query) {
            $query->latest("start_at")->limit(4);
        },
        "events.address"
    ])->orderBy("events.start_at")->paginate(4);
```

Is it possible? Please tell me how to implement this. thanks.

**Update:**
I tried with join, yes it works but not properly:

```
Schools::whereHas("events")
        ->select("schools.*")
        ->join("event_school", "schools.id", "=", "event_school.school_id")
        ->join("events", function ($join) {
            $join->on("events.id", "=", "event_school.event_id")
                ->whereDate("events.start_at", ">=", Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d"))
                ->limit(4);
        })
        ->join("addresses", "events.address_id", "=", "addresses.id")
        ->groupBy("schools.id")
        ->orderBy("events.start_at")
```

I'm getting all events. `->whereDate("events.start_at", ">=", Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d"))` not work, and not load addresses

Comment: Following your update, you can (and should) still use `->with()` alongside this join. If you don't, and try to access `$school->events` (which is the Laravel relationship), you'll get every related event instead of the latest 4.

Comment: @TimLewis, thx it's work

Comment: Excellent! Feel free to add the complete solution below; avoid editing it into the question as that doesn't work with the question/answer format of Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
    School::whereHas("events")
        ->select("schools.*")
        ->join("event_school", "schools.id", "=", "event_school.school_id")
        ->join("events", function ($join) {
            $join->on("events.id", "=", "event_school.event_id");
        })
        ->with([
            "events" => function ($query) {
                $query->whereDate("start_at", ">=", Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d"))
                    ->orderBy("start_at", "asc")
                    ->limit(4);
            },
            "events.address"
        ])
        ->groupBy("schools.id")
        ->orderBy("events.start_at");
```